# How can I run Generic Find method from a List on the Visual Studio Immediate Window?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I just want to debug calling Find from Immediate Window, is it possible?

```
            Customer found = listOfCustomers.Find(
                delegate(Customer cu)
                {
                    return cu.Name.ToLower().Contains("adam");
                }
            );
```

Comment: No it isn't you cannot execute a delegate method in the immediate window because of the way the compiler creates closures for these methods when the code is actually compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by many others, you cannot use the immediate window to do this.  I do have another suggestion that might work well for you.  I use it all the time and it is the best tool I've used in a long time.

[Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx) is a project from Microsoft that exposes the C# and VB.NET compilers to developers.  That is cool for a number of other reasons, but one in particular pertains to your needs.  It includes a C# Interactive Window.

While it is a CTP (hasn't even made a beta release yet), I've found it to be quite stable.  The June 2012 CTP supports VS2010, while the September 2012 CTP supports *only* VS2012.

You can reference other DLLs (both system and project) using the `#r` directive, and then use normal C# code and plug away.  It supports nearly all of the language features (I think async/await, PInvoke, dynamic, and a few other things aren't).  Here's a sample of it's output.

```
Microsoft (R) Roslyn C# Compiler version 1.1.20524.4
Loading context from 'CSharpInteractive.rsp'.
Type "#help" for more information.
> var strarr = new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h" };
> strarr
string[8] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h" }
> strarr.TakeWhile(s => s != "e")
TakeWhileIterator { "a", "b", "c", "d" }
> #r "D:\SVN\Lucene.Net\Trunk\bin\Lucene.Net.dll"
> using Lucene.Net.Store;
> var d = new RAMDirectory();
> d.Dispose()
<void>
> strar
(1,1): error CS0103: The name 'strar' does not exist in the current context
> #reset
Resetting execution engine
Loading context from 'CSharpInteractive.rsp'.
>
```

As you can see, you can use lambdas (you can use anonymous methods as well) as well as other language features.  I also referenced the Lucene.Net dll that's on my computer, and then was able to import the namespace and use the types.  You can also reference an entire project my right-clicking on it and selecting "Reset Interactive from Project", but I've found that it sometimes will throw an error and not work.

If you're looking for a tool to play around with code without having to run the debugger, I would recommend looking into Roslyn.

Comment: looks promising, I'm checking this out

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately in the immediate window you cannot call lambda expressions `(obj => obj.something == something)` or anonymous methods `(delegate () { })`.

You may want to add some unit tests to test your solution or create a small Helper class with a method that contains your example code and run that from the immediate window.